# Stuck with a Homogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $x>0, y>0$, find the general solution to the differential equation,

$x \frac{dy}{dx} = y + \frac{x}{\ln y - \ln x}$,

giving your answer in the form $y e^\frac{y}{x}=f(x)$.

I realised it was homogeneous and made the substitution $y=vx$, reaching $v \ln v - v = \ln x + c$, however from this point I can’t see how to manipulate it to get what the textbook says the answer should be, which is $y e^\frac{y}{x} = Ax^2$.

Have I made a mistake in getting to where I have, or if I have reached this point correctly, what hint can you give me to help me manipulate what I have towards the correct answer?

Comment: your result is correct  $$v \ln v - v = \ln x + c$$

Comment: Thank you - am I just missing the obvious link of getting it into the desired form?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the book's answer

Comment: Thank you - I thought I was just being silly!

Answer (score 1):

$$x \frac{dy}{dx} = y + \frac{x}{\ln y - \ln x}$$
$$x \frac{dy}{dx} -y= \frac{x}{\ln(\frac  yx)}$$
$$\implies \left (\frac yx \right)'=\frac{1}{x\ln (\frac yx)}$$
It's separable
$$\int \ln \left (\frac yx \right) d\frac yx=\int \frac{dx}{x}$$
Getting your result
$$\frac yx \ln \left (\frac yx \right)- \frac yx =\ln x +C$$
Take exponential on both sides
$$\left (\frac yx e^{-1}\right)^{\frac yx}=Ax$$
A term is clearly missing in the book's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written as
$$
y'=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{\ln(y/x)}
$$
Set $u=y/x$. Then $$
xu=y\quad \text{and thus}\quad xu'+u=y'=u+\frac{1}{\ln u},
$$
and therefore
$$
xu'=\frac{1}{\ln u}
$$
or
$$
(\ln u)u'=\frac{1}{x}
$$
or
$$
(u\ln u-u)'=(\ln u)u'=\frac{1}{x}=(\ln x)'
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{y}{x}(\ln(y/x)-1)=u\ln u -u=\ln x+c
$$

Comment: So the final line I have reached so far is correct! How can I manipulate it into the form the question wants however?